# Highcharts - How to force line chart to be visible above X Axis

Tags: highcharts

When plotting a line chart where there are values equal to the `yAxis.min` value, the line is hidden underneath the X Axis.

I have the Y Axis minimum set to 0 and the data set contains zeros

Here is an example:

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 0, 0, 0, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }]
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/egQH8/1/

If I increase the values to say 0.2, you can just see the line beginning to appear: http://jsfiddle.net/2RCdV/1/

Is there anything I can do to get round this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `min: 0` and add `startOnTick: false`.

That will make Highcharts compute the min value automatically and since it's no longer starting on the tick it'll draw the 0 yAxis line just a few pixels above the xAxis.

See it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/egQH8/2/).

Comment: It works great unless you set the line thickness to be 4 for example: http://jsfiddle.net/zL96uanu/. How do we fix for this case?

Comment: @elise-chant: I haven't touched HighCharts in a few years so I think I can't help you with this. Since it seems it is drawing 2px above the grid line and rest (below it) is cut off, maybe you could "hack it" by re-adding `min` to the `yAxis` but setting it to `-0.5` or similar. Other than that... no idea, sorry.

Comment: is there a similar setting as startOnTick, but for the top area of the chart? so there isnt as much white space/padding on top if no data plotted there?

Comment: @mike01010 Don't remember, sorry. Haven't used Highcharts in many years...

Answer (score 0):

we fixed this like this for 4px lines:

```
// This fixes the "thin lines at top & bottom of chart" bug
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'setChartSize', function (proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
  if (includes(['line','spline'], get(this, 'options.chart.type'))) {
    this.clipBox.height += 6;
    this.clipBox.y -= 3;
  }
});
```